# IdClass is not defined in class "Hello"

Tags: scala, hibernate, spring-boot

**"I want to get the value of the user Id from the Hello class to the goldUser of the Hello world But not able to get it. Getting @Idclass "No identifier specified for entity:" error."**

**What am I doing wrong or what should be the approach to get the value of the user id from the Hello table.**

```
  @Entity
    @Table(name ="Greetings")
    class HelloWorld {

      @Id
      @IdClass(classOf[Hello])
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.Lazy)
      @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
      @BeanProperty
      var goldUser: Hello = _

      @Column(name = "morning")
      @BeanProperty
      var morning: Long = _

      @Column(name = "aftrnoon")
      @BeanProperty
      var afternoon: Long = _

    }"




    "@Entity
    @Table(name = "Hello")
    class Hello {
      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      @Column(name = "id")
      @BeanProperty
      var userId: Long = _
    }
```

> ```
> "org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'goldEntityManager' defined in class path
> ```
>
> resource [in/happysellers/webapp/gold/GoldMorningConfig.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity:
>   in.happysellers.webapp.gold.dotprints.DotPrints
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
>   ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: in.happy.webapp.gold.greetingprints.HelloWorld
>         at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:231)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:775)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:250)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:231)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:274)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
>         at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.3.9.Final.jar:5.3.9.Final]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
>         ... 21 common frames omitted"

Comment: Who are you quoting at the start of the question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you `import` that class:

```
import javax.persistence.IdClass;
```